# How can I rename my town in Animal Crossing?

Tags: animal-crossing-wild-world

I got my son Animal Crossing for the DS for Christmas and he thought it might be fun to name his town after a fish:
[image: Pelly: THis is the Crap civic center. What can I help you with?]

We didn't notice until he'd invested some time in his new character.  After a good laugh, I tried to help him rename his town and rebuilding seemed to be the only option:

[image: So, you really want to get rid of Crap?]

He's pretty nervous about proceeding and I don't know what to suggest.  Will he lose everything?  It sure sounds like it.

The only other think I can think of is that he has a character on the Wii version of Animal Crossing and there seems to be a way to move character between them.  We're not at home at the moment for me to experiment.  Can we console him by promising that he can move his Wii Animal Crossing character to his DS?  I guess that's unlikely too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, isn't a Crappie another type of fish? When life gives you lemons... :P

Comment: I don't think it it possible to rename a town and keep the same setup/animals in it. Also, thank you for the laugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuilding the town means that you are erasing the game data and starting fresh.  Unfortunately there is no way to rename you town.

Transferring your Wild World(DS) character to City Folk(Wii) will **ONLY** keep the catalog and hairstyle of the character.  Items and money are not transfered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i don't think there is a way to rename your town without rebuilding it. Maybe you could write on the town bulletin board you have changed the name of your town but everyone will still call it the town of crap… :(

Answer (score 0):

When the character becomes mayor , he can rename the city.
To be mayor you must have all the golden tools , a perfect environnement town , a tree for every kinds of fruits , the bigest house and nookington . the , just speak to tortimer , the actual mayor , ona holiday.